# How to start my Windows Service at RunTime or at OnAfterInstall

Tags: delphi, windows-services

*History*

I am building a `Windows Service` as part of my `Platform Application` to handle updates and server functions, so it *can* be installed in machines different than where the `Client Application` is installed. It uses UDP to send and receive broadcast messages, and TCP to to handle more sensitive and most important messages.

*Objective*

I want that my Application could be easily installed by the end user, just by copying the executable files in the computers and when executing them. The main application should verify if the user is an administrator, create the configuration files, and then install the Windows Service and run it, so when non administrative users log in, they won't receive any error from my Application regarding administrative rights. The goal is to make most configurations without the need a present technician, since database will be remote.

*Problem*

My Service is being installed normally with the command `MyService.exe /install` but it is not starting automatically. The only way to start it is to go on `Control Panel > Admin Tools > Services` and do it manually. I tryed to call `net start MyService` through my application but I receive `invalid service name` at the shell. I tryied the `executable name`, the `display name` and the `object name` of the service, but none of them worked. This is the object of my TService:

```
object ServiceMainController: TServiceMainController
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = ServiceCreate
  DisplayName = 'PlatformUpdateService'
  Interactive = True
  AfterInstall = ServiceAfterInstall
  AfterUninstall = ServiceAfterUninstall
  OnShutdown = ServiceShutdown
  OnStart = ServiceStart
  OnStop = ServiceStop
  Height = 210
  Width = 320
```

*Question*

What should I do to start my service by the code and not by the user hands? It would be the best if I could do it inside my client application, or when by itself after the `OnServiceAfterInstall` call.

Comment: When using `net start`, you need to supply the unique name that you put in the service module's `Name` property, which is by default `Service1`.

Comment: PS - I would highly recommend not to start it with the after install event. Whatever app installs it should be the same app which starts it. Have you looked at InnoSetup?

Comment: I will take a look. I also could start the service this way you told.

Comment: net start/stop should work with either `Name` or `DisplayName` of the service (neither seem to be *MyService* BTW). Better try calling `StartService` in 'AfterInstall' though..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Indeed that's a question of the service installation implementation. I would naturally assume that if an installer such as InnoSetup was installing the service, then the same installer should also take care of starting the service as well.

Comment: @Jerry - I don't disagree with that. However the service doesn't seem to be installed via an installer in this case.

Comment: @EASI I once investigated if I could install a service by right-clicking on the EXE and showing options in the context menu to install/uninstall/start/stop a service EXE. I then discovered such rich UI features are not necessarily possible for a service. You need a sister-application which is responsible for managing this service. Naturally the same thing that installs it should also start it - I personally wouldn't make the service to start its self.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz But something has to install it, I'm assuming this service will be deployed in some manner, and I wouldn't expect the end user to open a command prompt to install it.

Comment: @Jerry - The executable for the service installs the service with the `/install` parameter, also stated in the question.

Comment: As I think I told in *Objective*, I would like to `install` and `start` the service through the `client application` in case it does not find the `service` in it's `UDP Broadcast`

Comment: You should also think that, with all Windows bugs and viruses and crazy users, it is dangerous to let the service be installed and started only by the installer, as if there is any problem that stops the service from work, you will have to re-install the whole application, and I should it's better not, by correcting the error from the main application, which may be able to re-install and start the service to get things working again.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a sample `StartService` call, in `AfterInstall` event:

```
procedure TServiceMainController.ServiceAfterInstall(Sender: TService);
var
  Manager, Service: SC_HANDLE;
begin
  Manager := OpenSCManager(nil, nil, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
  Win32Check(Manager <> 0);
  try
    Service := OpenService(Manager, PChar(Name), SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
    Win32Check(Service <> 0);
    try
      Win32Check(StartService(Service, 0, PChar(nil^)));
    finally
      CloseServiceHandle(Service);
    end;
  finally
    CloseServiceHandle(Manager);
  end;
end;
```

However I'm not sure it will work for you, as normally you should have success with `net start` too.

Comment: +1 But I don't much care for the bool casting. What's wrong with Win32Check(Manager<>0)?

Comment: @David - Thanks! The bool casting does not generate any code unlike the comparison. But the reason I prefer it, is it looks more natural to me. No big deal though..

Comment: Relying on implementation details doesn't seem at all natural to me, but each to their own.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i think it depends on your background and which languages you normally work with, Personally i agree with you, but i primarily work with delphi these days for native win32 development.

Comment: What does the Bool cast mean on Win64? I guess it's a compiler error. The docs say that a return value of 0 indicates failure which is my queue to test against zero. Of course, when the return type happens to be BOOL, then you can treat that as a boolean, even though the prevailing C language when BOOL was invented had no boolean type.

Comment: @David - No compiler error, why? The Bool cast does not mean anything special, it just means to treat the number as a Bool. The compiler does not even generate any code for the cast in either 32 or 64 bit. When it is evaluated, the only condition that it is false is it is 0, either it is UInt64 or something else. And why cast the return of an api to a boolean, Win32Check expects a bool.

Comment: Under Win64, what is Bool($100000000)? Once again, the condition for failure is return value equal to zero.

Comment: @David - It is 'true'. Tested with XE2 but I'd be surprised if it turned out otherwise in newer compilers. You can find it in the api too. See f.i. [DialogProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which returns an INT_PTR, *"..Typically, the dialog box procedure should return TRUE..."* Anyway, I'll edit the answer...

Comment: System Error `1053` *service did not respond to start request in time*

Comment: Using Windows 7 64 and XE3 - Is `Win32Check` really necessary?

Comment: @EASI How do you propose checking for errors? Win32Check is the way smart programmers do it.

Comment: @EASI - If there hadn't been a Win32Check you wouldn't find out the reason: *"service did not respond..". The error is related with your service.

Comment: This is a major side issue, but I can't see why Bool($100000000) evaluates to true? It can't just take the low 4 bytes because they are 0. So it must emit code to test <>0. I'm thousands of miles from a compiler now so I cannot check. Anyway, never mind too much. I can sate my curiosity when I have compiler again.