# How to build a software update service which could update itself too?

Tags: delphi, windows-services, auto-update

I know that many software are updated by a windows service installed together. I made the service to serve as an update helper and a data server for my client application. But I am stuck on how do I control my client application from this service.

First my service will check for updates on the remote server and then download files.

It will broadcast the news to clients which will ask users if they want to update now or the next execution.

On the time to update, the client application can not delete it's own executable file, so, it would make sense if it asks the server to do it while it's not executing, and then when finished deleting and renaming the files, it would re-execute the client.

If the service is in session 0, it could not be able to re-execute the client to the same user session.

The other possible problem is when the very service would need an update. It could be solved by been updated by the client instead of itself.

So, in the case of updating client and server, should I need to create a third application to do the job. if this 3rd application is a console app, it would be no problem to execute it from the service, right?

If there is a solution that doesn't include this 3rd app, it would be the best.

---

*Note:*

The service is not just an update service, but a server to inform user access and rights. The main client application will not access the `user information database` directly.

Comment: Make it make a copy of its self upon startup and run that copy

Comment: I wouldn't start here. A service just to update desktop software is surely not the right solution.

Comment: Actually I jumped to comment too quickly - can't work like that with services

Comment: What our company established with our software's primary server service is encapsulating all functionality inside a DLL and the service is just a shell which calls that DLL. The actual threads run from within the DLL. That makes it easier to update the business rule without touching the shell.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I made a note on the question to ensure the service will do more than just updates.

Comment: @JerryDodge, DLL is a good option, but solves only the service update problem, not the client application close, update and open. Is it Ok to set an UDP and a TCP listeners to receive and handle messages inside de DLL this case?

Comment: @JerryDodge, could you elaborate an answer based on your comms, and considering this other question as tech information about my goals? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324174/how-to-start-my-windows-service-at-runtime-or-at-onafterinstall

Comment: @EASI: I think Jerry is suggesting that the client app could also use DLLs, then the app itself would not need to be updated. It could simply unload, replace, and reload the DLLs it needs.

Comment: One DLL can be created which is spawned from this service which is dedicated to updating files. This DLL needs to be designed in a way that it its self should never have to be updated. It would have to be responsible for stopping / unloading all DLL's which are attached, replacing them, then resuming their usage. I'm working on an update system myself in a similar manner which uses a JSON file to hold instructions for the update.

Comment: However when worse comes to worse, you may as well require a restart and schedule your app to complete its updates on either shutdown or startup. In my case I have installations which shouldn't require a computer restart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If the service is in session 0, it could not be able to re-execute the client to the same user session.

Yes, it would, if you use `CreateProcessAsUser()` to specify the user account and the desktop to run the app on.  The client could convey that info to the service before terminating itself.

But in any case, updating an exe requires it to stop running first.  So when updating the service, especially since the service does more than just handle client updates, it would be safer to use an installer to stop the service, replace the exe, and restart the service.  In which case, why not do the client update using an installer as well?  The downloaded update could be a self-contained installer that stops both client and service as needed, replaces the files, and then either has the client or service delete the installer after it exits, or the installer can ask Windows to delete the installer upon the next OS reboot.

Comment: I have found these tips about CreateProcessAsUser() in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/31bfa13d-982b-4b1a-bff3-2761ade5214f/calling-createprocessasuser-from-service and I will try to develop a solution for Delphi.